# What can i use instead of 'readonly' for checkbox in my form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am using a checkbox in my code, I want to add a `readonly` property to the textbox, but I saw that `readonly` property cannot be added to checkbox. The suggested alternative is to set `disabled` to `true`.

But the case is if i set `disabled` property to `true`. I cannot get the checkbox value server side. I want a solution that sets the checkbox readonly and can get value in server side.

How can I do this?

This is my view:

```
<input id="AddNewProductCategory" class="" type="checkbox" tabindex="1900" name="addnewproductcategory" value="1" checked="checked">
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jq('#AddNewProductCategory').attr('checked',true);

});
```

In my server:

```
$check_box_val = $this->ci->input->post('addnewproductcategory');
```

I am using CodeIgniter and jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a hidden field  -

```
<input id="AddNewProductCategoryHidden" class="" type="hidden" tabindex="1900" name="addnewproductcategoryhidden" value=""/>
```

then set that when the checkbox gets clicked -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jq('#AddNewProductCategory').attr('checked',true);
jq('#AddNewProductCategoryHidden').val('true');

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Insert in HTML: `<input type="hidden" name="addnewproductcategory" value="1" />` and disable the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a `<input type='hidden'>` with the value 1 or 0 and disable the checkbox